# Can I define my own custom character shapes in ncurses?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, customization, ncurses

Title says pretty much everything. Once upon a time when I was under 13, my older bro did in BorlandPascal a thing which amazed me. He defined kind of table [8][8] with values of 1 and 0, meaning respectively foreground and background. Having several of such tables he could somehow redefine default ASCII characters to look like in these tables. I have no idea how it was done, but it worked.

My question is: can I do similar thing in ncurses, and if I can then how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. What ncurses does is generating [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) which are interpreted by the terminal. There are no codes for altering the font. (Althou there have been extensions propesed no commonly used terminal supports them, neither does ncurses.) And there is no generic way of communicating with the terminal through some kind of side channel for changing the font. But there might ways in some specific situations.

If you have direct access to a Linux console for example you could could do all sorts of things, much like in Borland Pascal. But it will likely be more messy and less impressive.

Comment: Wow, I certainly didn't expect answer after over a year from sumbitting this question. Thanks for the effort, dude :) Shame though, that it's not possible. However I dropped this subject a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

As the selected answer explains, this is not possible for NCurses to render custom glyphs. ncurses only manipulates the terminal screen state via escape codes *(Clearing and rewriting lines to achieve interactivity)*.

However it should be noted that's **very possible to use custom glyphs in the terminal via custom fonts**.

This is what Powerline does *(a popular terminal UI status line for vim, tmux and friends)*: https://github.com/powerline/fonts

By patching the fonts, you can inject your glyphs into the existing font being used by the terminal, which then you can access and render via ncurses as any other character.

Of course this is not ideal solution, but with some auto patching of the fonts, and careful testing, it makes it possible to build an app that uses custom glyphs—*when your really in a pinch for more expressive UI tools than ncurses can offer.*

Further reading: https://apw-bash-settings.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fontpatching.html